# Given a package name, how can I find out what will change if I install the package?

Tags: apt, package-management

Given a set of `apt` commands and packages to apply (e.g. `install foo bar baz`, `autoremove quux blerg bang`), is there a way to calculate the diff of the system state that will be produced if I run the commands?

By "system state" I don't merely mean whether a given package will install/remove other packages, but what kinds of actual changes get produced -- files being deleted or moved, scripts getting run, et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

You can run apt-get in simulate mode, e.g.:

with

```
sudo apt-get --simulate install foo bar baz
```

or without `sudo` also

```
apt-get --simulate install foo bar baz
```

This won't change anything on your system but will print out what will apt-get do when you run that command.

Comment: That will tell me what other packages will be installed, but I'm interested at a more granular level: what files get changed, added, removed, et cetera.

Comment: @JohnFeminella I don't think that there is a software for that, at least I never heard about such.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for more debugging. The problem with this is... that the information is way too much to be useful for anyone without knowledge of what he's reading. But here it is:

```
sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgDPkgProgressReporting=true -o Debug::pkgPackageManager=true -o Debug::pkgDPkgPM=true install package
```

But hey, there's a bunch of other ways you can do this. For example:

```
apt-get --print-uris install package
## This will print a lot of url. Download them.
wget uris
dpkg-deb -c *.deb
```

This will show you the contents. You will need to evaluate the control scripts (post/pre inst/rm) separated.

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks! This is still at the package-level though, rather than at the file level.

Comment: @JohnFeminella if you want, you could use `dpkg --no-act some-1.0.deb`, but again, it would be more information that is really helpful

Comment: See also http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/491

Comment: @bodhi.zazen not sure how that is relevant.

Comment: Guess it depends on what the OP wants exactly. The above link gives info from the changelogs and where to go for additional info. Frankly, I am not sure how running diff on binaries/libs helps either. Perhaps the OP would like gentoo ;p

Comment: @bodhi.zazen that link is for `apticron` usage. He wants verbose output of all the files that are changed, removed, created, etc. when installing packages.